# Moving ::before and ::after

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to solve an exercise but I can not do it.

In theory I have to move the ::before and ::after elements of the .calendar element in the proper way so they can be placed just like the picture.

Please move the ::before and ::after of the  element in the proper way so they can be placed just like the picture.

Change their colors as well so they can have the same color, and apply the border-radius to the ::before and ::after of the  to make them look like a ring in 2 dimensions seen from the front.

```css
.calendar {
  top: 0em;
  left: 1em;
  padding-top: 5px;
  width: 80px;
  background: #ededef;
  font-size: 54px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
  border-radius: 3px;
  position: absolute;
}

.calendar em {
  display: block;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #04599a;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
}

.calendar:before,
.calendar:after {
  content: "";
  float: left;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #111;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #fff;
  position: absolute;
}

.calendar:before {
  left: 11px;
}

.calendar:after {
  right: 11px;
}

.calendar em:before,
.calendar em:after {
  content: "";
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 15px;
  background: grey;
  z-index: 5;
  border-radius: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}

.calendar em:before {
  left: 30px;
}

.calendar em:after {
  right: 13px;
  top: -16px;
  left: 2px;
  bottom: 10px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<p class="calendar">7 <em></em></p>
```

[image: My calendar should look like this]

Comment: @isherwood float is ignored when element is positioned absolutely.

Comment: Add to positioned `:before/:after` pseudoelements `top` and `left/right` properties. How these elements should know where is their position? And one semantics note: `p` isn't the correct HTML tag for this type of information.

Comment: There is something not quite nice in using pseudo-elements BUT still requiring an empty element in HTML to work fine.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be using floats in general. They needlessly complicate positioning and aren't necessary. There are more modern ways to align things if that's what you're after.

Mostly, just position your elements with `top` and `left`:

```css
.calendar {
  top: 0em;
  left: 1em;
  padding-top: 5px;
  width: 80px;
  background: #ededef;
  font-size: 54px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
  border-radius: 3px;
  position: absolute;
}

.calendar em {
  display: block;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #04599a;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
}

.calendar:before,
.calendar:after {
  content: "";
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #111;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
}

.calendar:before {
  left: 11px;
}

.calendar:after {
  right: 11px;
}

.calendar em:before,
.calendar em:after {
  content: "";
  margin: 10px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 15px;
  background: grey;
  z-index: 5;
  border-radius: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -16px;
}

.calendar em:before {
  left: 52px;
}

.calendar em:after {
  right: 13px;
  left: 2px;
  bottom: 10px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<p class="calendar">7 <em></em></p>
```